# Proving an integral identity for a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, mean-value-theorem

> Let  $ f :  \left[ 0, 1 \right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous function. Knowing that: $$ \int_0^1 (2x-1)f(x)dx = 0 $$ Show that $ \exists c \in \left(0,1\right)$ such that: $$ \int_0^c (x-c)(f(x)-f(c))dx = 0 $$

Let $F$ be a primitive of $f$ such that $F(0) = 0$. ( i.e. $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$
and $F'(x)=f(x)$ )

I have attempted to solve this and managed to show that there exists $ c, t \in [0,1] $ such that $ F(c) = F(1)/2 = f(t)/2 $ using the mean value theorem:
$$  2\int_0^1 x f(x)dx = \int_0^1 f(x) dx = \frac{F(1)-F(0)}{1-0} = f(t) \\ $$
Doing the first integral by parts we get:
$$ \int_0^1 xf(x)dx = xF(x)\vert_0^1 \; - \int_0^1 F(x)dx = \\ = F(1)  -\int_0^1F(x)dx $$

Using the mean value theorem, we get that:
$$ \exists c\in [0,1] \text{ such that } \int_0^1F(x)dx = F(c) $$
Plugging everything in the first equation gives us:
$$ 2( F(1) - F(c) ) = F(1) = f(t) \\ \Rightarrow F(1) = 2 F(c) \\ \Rightarrow F(c) = \frac{F(1)}{2} = \frac{f(t)}{2}  $$
I do not know if these results will help solving this exercise or not.

Comment: crossposted and answered (in a comment) at https://mathoverflow.net/q/440623/11260

Comment: Comment did not solve the problem.

Comment: why did it not?